# What does the use of synchronized() mean in this case?

Tags: java, synchronization

I am reading through some of the Android Java code, and I came across this:

```
public void registerObserver(T observer) {
    if (observer == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The observer is null.");
    }
    synchronized(mObservers) {
        if (mObservers.contains(observer)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Observer " + observer + " is already registered.");
        }
        mObservers.add(observer);
    }
}
```

I have only seen `synchronized` used as a keyword before a variable or class. What does it do in this instance?

Comment: In android studio, hold `CTRL` and click on the method name and it will bring up a list of usages/the declaration.

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html#synchronized-blocks-instance-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `synchronized` means accessing the data of `mObservers` with some sort of locking to ensure thread safety. Other threads cannot access `mObservers` until the current thread finished with the `synchronized` block.

Check out [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

Answer (score 1):

If any other thread encounters a `synchronized(mObservers)` in this member function or any other member function whilst a particular thread is inside the synchronized block above, then that thread will halt until the particular thread has exited block.

This can be useful if `mObservers` can only be changed by one thread at any time, and is a finer-grained synchronization technique than synchronizing on a class or instance.